# How are temperature and other state variables formally defined in terms of space?

Tags: thermodynamics

Are temperature and other state variables formally defined in thermodynamics as values in points in space such as in a field, or are they defined as values that describe a region of space such as the system you are interested in?

Comment: A system you are interested in. You can represent anything you want as "points in space," even if you aren't referring to ACTUAL space. The temperature can be on an axis, velocity on the other, and so on and so on, as long as they aren't qualities that interfere with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temperature is only defined for a system *at equilibrium*. You can have a system that is composed of multiple sub-systems, each one at equilibrium, in which case you can assign a temperature to each one. If you want to assign a temperature to every point in a fluid, for example, you need to assume that it is locally at equilibrium at every point.

It's worth expanding on what equilibrium means. Equilibrium means that the distribution over microstates is unchanging in time: $\partial p/\partial t = 0$. This in turn implies that entropy is unchanging in time, which means there is no heat exchange. Obviously, you cannot actually have two systems in equilibrium at different temperatures in contact, because there will be heat exchange. However, for small enough temperature differences and small enough time scales for relaxation, the distribution over microstates is *nearly* unchanging so the notion of temperature can still be applied and is useful.